# How to create tpl files in prestashop?

Tags: php, html, prestashop

I know the following functions is used for displaying form in prestashop.

```
     public function getContent()
        {
            $this->_html="<h2>".$this->name."</h2><form>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type='text' name='username'><br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type='text' name='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='save'>
</form>";
            return $this->_html;
      }
```

But i want to know how to do that same operation using `.tpl` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TPL files can be displayed in module hooks:

```
public function hookLeftColumn($params)
{
  $this->smarty->assign(
    array(
      'name' => $this->name,
    )
  );
  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'example.tpl');
}
```

example.tpl:

`<h2>{$name}</h2>
<form>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type='text' name='username'><br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type='text' name='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='save'>
</form>`